# Can't run jupyter notebook after installing

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to run jupyter notebook through pycharm and cmd as well but I keep getting the following error and I wasn't able to find a solution for it. Is there anyone that knows how I fix this?

```
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\31611\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2141, in initialize
    self._init_asyncio_patch()
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2117, in _init_asyncio_patch
    nest_asyncio.apply()
  File "c:\users\31611\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 14, in apply
    raise ValueError('Can\'t patch loop of type %s' % type(loop))
ValueError: Can't patch loop of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: I have the exact same Problem. I can run jupyter-notebook in the terminal however and it seems to work there.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a different stackoverflow post and this fixed my issue

```
pip install nest_asyncio==1.5.3
```

Comment: It is recommended to reference that post in you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently, installed package inside the docker container environment and after running *CMD jupyter notebook* got the same error message. Re-installing jupyter==1.0.0 from scratch helped to resolve the issue.